# After running cook book, the httpd installation is not getting done

Tags: chef-infra, httpd.conf, chef-recipe

I wrote chef recipe to install httpd and to enable and start the same. but getting the below error.

```
Recipe: (chef-apply cookbook)::(chef-apply recipe)
  * apt_package[httpd] action install

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `install` on resource 'apt_package[httpd]'
    ================================================================================

    Chef::Exceptions::Package
    -------------------------
    httpd is a virtual package provided by multiple packages, you must explicitly select one

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In server.rb

      6: package 'httpd' do
      7:        action :install
      8: end
      9: 

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in server.rb:6:in `run_chef_recipe'

    apt_package("httpd") do
      package_name "httpd"
      action [:install]
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :package
      cookbook_name "(chef-apply cookbook)"
      recipe_name "(chef-apply recipe)"
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=14.8.12
    platform=ubuntu
    platform_version=18.04
    ruby=ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=/usr/bin/chef-apply
    executable=/opt/chefdk/bin/chef-apply

[2019-01-29T10:14:30+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/devopsdevops95/.chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2019-01-29T10:14:30+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2019-01-29T10:14:30+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Package: apt_package[httpd] ((chef-apply cookbook)::(chef-apply recipe) line 6) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Package: httpd is a virtual package provided by multiple packages, you must explicitly select one
```

I tried many solutions like apt-get update before running recipe but no use.

```
chef -v
Chef Development Kit Version: 3.6.57
chef-client version: 14.8.12
delivery version: master (5fb4908da53579c9dcf4894d4acf94d2d9ee6475)
berks version: 7.0.7
kitchen version: 1.24.0
inspec version: 3.2.6

OS -
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

package 'httpd' do
        action :install
end

file '/var/www/html/index.html' do 
        content '<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'
end

service 'httpd' do
```

I expect it to install httpd without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining the apt_preference resource?
https://docs.chef.io/resource_apt_preference.html

The apt_preference resource allows for the creation of APT preference files. Preference files are used to control which package versions and sources are prioritized during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it done.

1. The httpd cook book is nomore in use- https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/httpd
2. I used the below recipe

```rb
execute 'sudo apt-get update' do
  command 'sudo apt-get update'
end

apt_package 'apache2' do
  action :install
end

file '/var/www/html/index.html' do
  content '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>'
end

service 'apache2' do 
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```